# How to quiet the cooling fan on an eMachines T3508?

Tags: cooling, fan, desktop-computer, noise

I have an eMachines T3508 running XP on 384 MB of RAM. The problem is that the cooling fan revs up and gets very noisy when I do something that stresses the CPU, like watching a video or visiting a website with Flash advertisements. It's so loud that I can't hear the audio track in some videos I watch.

What it's doing makes sense I guess - the more work the CPU does, the more heat it generates, and the more cooling it needs. But is there a way to make the fan work just a tad less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be that the original heatsink compound isn't doing the job. I'd try pulling the heatsink, cleaning it and the top of the proc really well (rubbing alcohol, cotton cloth) and then using some good thermal paste and re-attach it.

Of course, you might open the case and make sure you haven't obstructed ventilation with any large dust bunnies first!

Comment: OMG the inside was filthy!  Good call.